# Stack Exchange app freezes when clicking on link

Tags: bug, android-app

App just freezes when I try to open any link. I can browse forums, settings and other stuffs but when I try to open questions app just stucks and every link in navigation is unresponsive.

I tried logging Out and logging back in, reinstalling app and deleting cache. None of that worked.

App Version: 1.0.95
Device Manufacturer: Xiaomi
Device Model: Redmi Note 8 Pro
OS Version: 9 (V10.4.5.0.PGGEUXM)

Comment: Probably related to the [ongoing API woes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391242/se-api-is-randomly-responding-with-site-is-required-errors-and-now-cors-errors).

Comment: is there anyting that can be done on my side?

Comment: No. The API is randomly returning errors. There's nothing any of us can do, except wait

Comment: okay. thank you for your time and fast response :)